# How to pass variable inside a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

In the dataTable creation I want to pass variable in the rendering of a column :

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
              { "aTargets": [ 2 ], "bSortable": false },
              { "aTargets": [ 2 ], "bSearchable": false },
              { "aTargets": [ 2 ],
              "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
              var url_ = full[1];
              return '<div style="text-align: center;">'+
              '<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="T&eacute;l&eacute;charger" onclick="telecharge("'+url_+'")">'+
              '<button class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i></button>'+
              '</a>'+
              '</div>';
              }
}
                       ]
```

At runtime I get error , so how to pass the variable `url_` ?

Comment: `'<a onclick="telecharge(\''+url_+'\')">'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need nest quotes properly and also need to escape inner quotes.

```
'<a onclick="telecharge(\''+url_+'\')">'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use es6 string templates like this:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
  { "aTargets": [ 2 ], "bSortable": false },
  { "aTargets": [ 2 ], "bSearchable": false },
  {
    "aTargets": [ 2 ],
    "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
      var url_ = full[1];
      return `<div style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="T&eacute;l&eacute;charger" onclick="telecharge(${url_})">
        <button class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i></button>
        </a>
        </div>`;
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: it does not work : I get `missing ) after argument list` , NB : I use PHP with Codeigniter , but not JSP !